# Starting my career as i'm not a native english speaker

Tags: performing

i think this question is a little bit weird, but i wanted to ask it anyway.
i don't live in a country with its main language as English. so i learned it myself. my speaking is not good enough right now but i've come a long way.

you may say why not just sing(rap) in your own language, the point is i feel i can express my feelings better in English and also its a global language so my dream is to rap for worldwide not just for one specific country.

i have a few obstacles which i wanted to share with you and take any advice if you have:

1- i have no one around that i can talk English to. even if there was, they couldn't help me with my mistakes and improving my Accent. how can i overcome this? fluenting my rapping and learning American accent.

2- i read in internet that some rappers started going to local producers and showing them lyrics or some beats and... so they could work together. which doesn't work for me. 90% of here doesn't even understand Eng, so showing my lyrics to them doesn't make sense.

3- this is somehow connected to number2. i'm new to this field and i have no one(lets make it crystal clear :) "NO ONE") around me in music industry. how am i supposed to find a producer for example?! or a guy help me record song with his stuff cause i'm not sure i can afford a good mic or sth else to record myself.

4- how to tell the world i'm here! i created an Instagram account. trying to put some quotes of my favorite artists to gain some traction. but i think there must be better ways to do that.

5- there is no one in my country that i can sign an Eng rap deal. how am i supposed to grow without that?

-- if you know anyone with same problems that finally made it and became someone, it would be appreciated to share with me

Comment: perhaps if you told us your locale, we could assist more ? Personally I think your use of English is fine. I am much less fluent than you in the languages that I know.

Comment: To be successful as a rapper you don't need to speak perfectly English. There are enough native English speaking rappers! But your success could just lay in the fact that you have your own original pictures in mind, your own phrasing and accent, and even it is not perfect English people like me would love and estimate it!

Comment: @bigbadmouse i live in middle east, already know Persian, Arabics, English, and a little bit Germans language

Answer (score 1):

To be successful as a rapper you don't need to speak perfectly English. There are enough native English speaking rappers! But your success could just lie in the fact that you have your own original pictures in mind, your own phrasing and accent, and even it is not perfect English people like me would love and estimate it! - But somehow you remind me of all the young boys who want to start a career as football players or all the girls who want become a model or "influencer". So I wouldn't start trying to look for producer but start your own  channel. Getting famous in this biz is harder than  to win the 6 in a lottery.

Example:

Müslüm is a Swiss entertainer with Turkish background and successful artist. He started his career when calling public offices like police center or journal offices and politicians etc.  asking silly funny question, recording the call and spreading on his youtube channel.

This video is criticizing  the doctors of medicine, the pharma industry the drug dealers  and he tells his song is the super vitamin.

here he is mocking about  a political party of the right corner that wants to send the migrants home.

Comment: First let me thank you so much for your answer.  so you advice me to create a channel and put my own raps there? Tnx OFC i'll do that. do u suggest me any other way in parallel for me to grow up my career?